# Upon submitting a webform, set a date field on the article node equals to "current time" + "X minutes"

Tags: 8, webforms, datetime

I am using the [Field Timer](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_timer) module to display countdown timer on my article node.

This module will take the value of the date/time field (my case: field_article_datetime) and convert it into a countdown timer in the display of the article.

I have a webform (machine name: ABC) attached as a field to the **article** content type so I can use `[webform_submission:node:nid]` to retrieve the **article nid** of the article to be updated.

The webform (machine name: ABC) has below element:

1) **Select** element (machine name: increase_time_in_minutes):

1. Text: Increase by 15 minutes (Value: 15)
2. Text: Increase by 30 minutes (Value: 30)
3. Text: Increase by 45 minutes (Value: 45)

And the article content type has below field:

1. date/time field (machine name: field_article_datetime) (the [Field Timer](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_timer) module is applied to this field)

When the webform "ABC" is submitted, I want to:

1. Fetch the article nid (`[webform_submission:node:nid]`)
2. Set the value of the date/time field (field_article_datetime) equal to **current time + increase_time_in_minutes**

**EXAMPLE:**

Say at **14/03/2019 08:30:15 PM**, a user has submitted the webform "ABC" and selected **Increase by 15 minutes** option from the select list... So I need the related article to be fetched and update the (field_article_datetime) to have the value of **14/03/2019 08:45:15 PM**

This way, the user will see a countdown timer for 15 minutes on the article node display page.

---

I am not a programmer, but I think the best Idea is to use a customwebformhandler.php file which will be enabled for the webform settings page.

I have created the file but I need help to finish it:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module_extras\Plugin\WebformHandler;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Serialization\Yaml;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

use Drupal\webform\WebformInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerBase;
use Drupal\webform\webformSubmissionInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission;


/**
 * Update a node entity from a webform submission.
 *
 * @WebformHandler(
 *   id = "Update a node",
 *   label = @Translation("Update a node"),
 *   category = @Translation("Entity Update"),
 *   description = @Translation("Updates a node from Webform Submissions."),
 *   cardinality = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
 *   results = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::RESULTS_PROCESSED,
 *   submission = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::SUBMISSION_REQUIRED,
 * )
 */

class SetTimerOnNodeWebformHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */

  // Function to be fired while submitting the Webform.
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
    // Get an array of the values from the submission.
    $values = $webform_submission->getData();

    // Fetch & Update node object from webform-submission.  
    //get current node or use any other way to get the current node
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
    $current_time = \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime(); 
    date_default_timezone_set('GMT');

    //get value from webform
    $increase = $values["increase_time_in_minutes"];

    //calculate new time
    $timer = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $current_time + $increase * 60);

    //add it to article field and save
    $node->field_article_datetime->value = $timer;
    $node->save();
  }
}
```

}

**Update #2:**
The below error is generated because of one missing `}` at the end of the file. (Stupid mistake)

**Update #1:**
Error logged in in the dblog after trying to add the webformhandler.php file to the webform:

```
ParseError: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in Composer\Autoload\includeFile() (line 59 of S:\######\dev.####\web\modules\custom\my_module_extras\src\Plugin\WebformHandler\SetTimerOnNodeWebformHandler.php) #0 S:\######\dev.#####\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('S:\\###### ...') #1 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Drupal\\my_module...') #2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Drupal\\my_module...') #3 S:\#######\dev.#####\web\core\lib\Drupal\Component\Plugin\Factory\DefaultFactory.php(96): class_exists('Drupal\\my_module...') #4 S:\#######\dev.#####\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Plugin\Factory\ContainerFactory.php(17): Drupal\Component\Plugin\Factory\DefaultFactory::getPluginClass('Update a node', Array, 'Drupal\\webform\\...')
```

Comment: Please elaborate on `attached as a field to the article content type`.  How is this done ?  Do you mean include as a block under article content type ?

Comment: I have added a new field of type webform and select the webform ABC from the select droodown list list of all available webforms.

Comment: you are right, I had never noticed that you could include webform as a field.  The solution I posted should work for this case as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this as your `submitForm`

```
$values = $webform_submission->getData();

//get current node or use any other way to get the current node
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
  $current_time = \Drupal::time()->getCurrentTime(); 
  date_default_timezone_set('GMT');

  //get value from webform
  $increase = $values["increase_time_in_minutes"];

  //calculate new time
  $timer = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $current_time + $increase * 60);

  //add it to article field and save
  $node->field_article_datetime->value = $timer;
  $node->save();
}
```

The answer asumes that you have included the webform as a block for article content types.  Another possibility is to include the webform as field and it should work exactly the same.

NOTE: before the webform handler works you have to enable your custom module and than go to your webform `settings > email/handlers` and include your handler

Comment: I have updated the webformhandler.php file with the code in your answer and successfully enabled the module... However, I cannot add the handler to the webform with an error logged in dblog... See the **Update #1** of my question please

Comment: You are missing a closing brace `}` of the class and also make sure that your file is placed in `MODULENAME/src/Plugin/WebformHandler/SetTimerOnNodeWebformHandler.php`

Comment: The drupal community is the best because of people just like you who are willing to help at any time. Thank you @GiorgosK you rock!

Comment: For other users who need a complete solution for similar issue, just copy the entire code available in my question above and paste it in your webformhandler.php file